# How can I implement a 'Lettrine' render in android?

Tags: android, text, render

I've just a little question about

How can I implement a 'Lettrine' (dropped initial capital letter) render in android? 
I mean, a widget that renders a lettrine automatically.

Here is an example of what I'm looking for:

[image]

I'm quite sure there is no "simple way" to do it, but if any could help...
All ideas are welcomed.

*If you are also interested in that kind of android widget, I'll be happy to collaborate
and to release our work under LGPL license ;-)*

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to put the text in a WebView with the appropriate CSS, and let the browser interpret the thing.

As for widgerts, all layouts in Android are rectangular. There is no easy way to do this. I think, you can achieve this with a custom [StaticLayout](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/text/StaticLayout.java/).